# Finding limits of the following function with the given conditions

Tags: calculus

I have a question regarding calculus:

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a continuous, differentiable function such that $f'$ is continuous, $f(2)=0$ (but $f(x)>0$ for all $x\neq2$) and $f'(2)=7$. Evaluate $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\left[\ln(f(2+3x)\sin(x))-\ln((f(2-5x)(x+1))\right]$.

In this case, the natural first step to do is to combine the $\ln$ function together:
$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\left[\ln\frac{f(2+3x)\sin(x)}{f(2-5x)(x+1)}\right]$

Since $f'$ is given, l'Hopital's rule is to be used.

However, no matter how I combine the terms together, the I will get something like $\ln0$ after taking limits. Is the limit in this case really $-\infty$? I guess there must be something that more than meets the eye, because I have not used the condition that $f(x)>0$, or is it just a formality to ensure that the $\ln$ function is well defined for positive values?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I may be wrong, but there seem to be a contradiction within your description of the problem: f AND f' continuous, $f'(2)>0$, $f(2)=0$ AND $f(x)>0$ for $x\neq2$!

Comment: Hi. I have no idea, but that is the condition being given to me. It may be strange to see why $f$ possesses such conditions, but I think we can find $f$ by by defining piecewise functions?

Comment: Recheck the conditions, with those conditions there simply exist no such function at all.

Comment: A sad thing is: that is how the problem is posed. I typed it exactly word for word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explain myself...

$f'(2)=7$, and $f'(x)$ continuous, thus $\exists \epsilon>0$ such as $f'(2-\epsilon)>0$.

$f(x)$ is increasing on $[2-\epsilon;2]$, and $f(2)=0$, so $f(2-\epsilon)<0$

Which is in contradiction with $f(x)>0$ for $x\neq2$